# The difference between Session::flash() and with() in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Good day to all guys, I am new to Laravel and wanted to understand if there are any contrasts between Session::flash and with() (or they are totally the same) when you want to show success message to user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/redirects):

> Redirecting to a new URL and flashing data to the session are usually done at the same time. Typically, this is done after successfully performing an action when you flash a success message to the session. For convenience, you may create a RedirectResponse instance and flash data to the session in a single, fluent method chain.

It's just syntax sugar to make it prettier.

Comment: Thank you for your attention and explanation, so what you mean is  Session.flash('success', 'Created') return redirect('/post') and just return redirect()->with('success', Created) are same and the latter is better choice right?

Comment: They're functionally the same. Which one is "better" is up to you. I prefer the `with()` syntax.

Comment: sorry dude I am afraid I have one more question. Look when we use Session::flash('success', 'Created') or with('success', 'Created') and then redirect user to, say, index page. Do we kind of pass "success" into index page like passing data from controller to view this is just an analogy. Or  'success' is put into DB depending on session driver and then we acces it from DB with Session::has('success','Created'). Please try to reply back it is very important for me